# obtener los usuarios no registrados

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo un probelma con mi proyecto, resulta que tengo dos tablas USERINFO y CHECKINOUT, la primera es la informacion de los usuarios y la segunda es la informacion del registro, cada vez que un usuario se registra se agrega una nueva entra, pero yo quiero obtener los usuarios que no se registraron en una fecha determina.

el codigo es el siguiente, el cual me arroja los usuarios que NO se registraron en esa fecha pero me arroja todos los usuarios ya que todos se registraron en otras fechas, deseo que me arroje LOS USUARIOS QUE NO SE REGISTRARON UNICA Y EXCLUSIVAMENTE en una fecha determinada.

este es el codigo:

```
select u.USERID, ch.CHECKTIME
from CHECKINOUT ch
inner join USERINFO u
on ch.USERID = u.USERID
where CONVERT(date,CHECKTIME,103) not in ('2019-09-19')
```

ayudenme porfavor, gracias

Comment: ¿qué gestor de bases de datos usas?

Comment: ESTOY UTILIZANDO SQLSERVER 2014

Comment: ¿Cuál es el datatype de la columna `CHECKTIME`? ¿Por qué la mareas tanto aquí: `CONVERT(date,CHECKTIME,103)`?

Comment: lo que sucede es que el datatype de CHECKTIME es DATETIME pero para las comparaciones necesito que sea UNICAMENTE DATE, pero si estoy mal, necesito algunas sugerencias porfavor. :,)

Comment: No entiendo bien. La consulta que tienes ahí devuelve los usuarios que no se registraron en esa fecha específica.  ¿No es eso lo que quieres? Se supone que los que no se registraron en esa fecha se registraron en las demás fechas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes buscar primero aquellos usuarios que SI se registraron en la fecha en cuestión y luego traer aquellos que ne estén en dicho conjunto:

```
select u.USERID
       from USERINFO u
       where u.USERID not in (select distinct USERID 
                                     from CHECKINOUT 
                                     where CONVERT(date,CHECKTIME) in ('2019-09-19')
                             )
```

Por cierto, con la versión de SQL Server puedes "truncar" un `datetime` mediante `CONVERT(date,<fechahora>)`

Comment: me funciono, muchas gracias!

Comment: Y si fuera en un rango de fechas porfavor? es decir quiero saber los usuarios que no se registraron, agrupados en fechas

Comment: Puedes hacer algo así por ejemplo `where CONVERT(date,CHECKTIME) between '2019-09-01' and '2019-09-19'`

Comment: solo me arroja los que nunca alguna vez se registraron en ese rango, lo que deseo es que me arroje los usuarios que no se registraron y en que fechas?

Comment: Entonces lo que tienes que hacer es agregar un `LEFT JOIN  CHECKINOUT` a `USERINFO` para  poder agregar es información

Comment: le dejare el link para que me entienda mejor, aun asi con left join no me arroja el resultado deseado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/295335/no-registrados-en-un-rango-de-fechas?noredirect=1#comment540481_295335

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/295335/no-registrados-en-un-rango-de-fechas