# FECHAS DE REGISTRO EN UN RANGO DE FECHAS

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo dos tablas CRONOGRAMA y REGISTROES, en la primera esta el HORARIO (DNI, FECHA, HORAINICIO,HORAFIN) de los usuarios y en la segunda esta los datos de su REGISTRO diario (DNI,FECHA, HORA,TIPO), con una consulta pude sacar los usuarios que se registraron en un rango de fechas:

```
select distinct r.dni, r.fecha
from Cronograma c
inner join RegistroES r
on c.dni=r.dni
where r.fecha between '2019-09-20' and '2019-09-21'
order by r.fecha
```

el resultado es:

```
dni |  fecha
----|---------
4   |  2019-09-20
5   |  2019-09-20
6   |  2019-09-20
1   |  2019-09-21
4   |  2019-09-21
5   |  2019-09-21
6   |  2019-09-21
```

pero lo que yo necesito, es saber quienes NO SE REGISTRARON y en que fechas en ese rango y que esten ordenados por fecha. Espero me ayuden gracias.
La tabla CRONOGRAMA tambien tiene el campo "fecha", el cual verifica si en esa fecha se registro.

Yo necesito saber los que no se registraron en ese rango de fechas y en que fechas.

La lista de usuarios y sus horarios estan en la tabla CRONOGRAMA

por ejemplo esta consulta me arroja el usuario que no se registro pero en una fecha especifica:

```
select distinct c.dni
from Cronograma c
inner join RegistroES r
on c.dni=r.dni
where c.dni not in (select dni from RegistroES where fecha = '2019-09-21')
```

Me arroja este resultado:

```
dni |
----|
2   |
3   |
```

como hago para que me arroje en un rango de fechas y en que fechas?

El resultado que quiero es:

```
dni |  fecha
----|---------
1   |  2019-09-20
2   |  2019-09-20
3   |  2019-09-20
2   |  2019-09-21
3   |  2019-09-21
```

que estos serian los Usuarios que no se registraron

Comment: Por favor poné un ejemplo del contenido de las tablas y del resultado que querés obtener.

Comment: edite la pregunta para que lo tengas mas claro

Comment: No le encuentro mucho sentido a lo que quieres hacer.  La consulta devolvería todos los usuarios que no se registraron en el rango de fechas, y cada usuario lo repetiría por cada fecha en que no se registró.  La lista de usuarios sería muy grande.

Comment: Lo que se desea es conocer en que fechas no seregistro, normalmente el rango sera de 1 semana o un mes exagerando para su control, ayudenme porfavor

Comment: o al menos que me muestre el numero de veces que no se registro dicho usuario

Answer (score 0):

Lo que estás buscando es una resta que puedes implementar con un `LEFT JOIN` o un `NOT IN`.

Quizá lo que te cueste encontrar es de dónde obtener las fechas en las que deberían haber registrado, para cotejarlas con aquellas en las que sí que hay registro. Se me ocurren dos opciones:

- Generando una tabla con los registros temporales que deberían existir
- A partir de registros temporales de otros usuarios `SELECT DISTNCT ...`

Una vez tengas este listado, sólo debes hacer un producto cartesiano (`JOIN` sin `ON`) con los usuarios y, a continuación, un `LEFT JOIN WHERE IS NULL` con los registros temporales.

Inténtalo y, si necesitas ayuda, modifica tu pregunta incorporando el dataset en SQL para poder importar las tablas y generar las consultas